# Python graphics on raspberry pi command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphics, pixel, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get / set screen pixels (draw picture, line, circle, box,  etc.) without starting x session. i tried google it but no success.

I am new to python. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the is no way to have graphics without x-session.

The best solution to this is to set boot to desktop and using pygame library create full screen window to draw graphics.